# Select PID by full command

Tags: ps

I need to select the PID of a Java process. If I run something like this: `ps -C java -o pid=`, it will select all the Java processes. I am after a specific process where the command used to start is `./java -jar /path/to/my/jar.jar`

If I try this: `ps -C "./java -jar /path/to/my/jar.jar" -opid=` it doesn't work because the selection is not right.

Does anyone know how I can select the PID based on the startup command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps aux | grep 'java -jar /path/to/my/jar.jar' | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'
```

Comment: ps aux | grep '[j]ava -jar /path/to/my/jar.jar' | awk '{print $2}'